# SQL Server Connection Limit

Tags: sql-server

What is the concurrent connection limit of SQL Server?

In the
[microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) ,it is saying "SQL Server allows a maximum of 32,767 user connections.".
Should we think that value as per SQL Server instance?
I mean Let's say we are using SQL Server high availability like the structure in [high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups). Then we will have had multi SQL Server instances. One of them must be master instance and rest of them are slave instances.

Then shortly;

1. Does 32,767 mean connection limit per instance?
2. If so;
   Let's say we have 1 master instance and 3 slave replica instances in  our SQL Server High Availability?

1 * 32,767 + 3 * 32,767 = 137,068

Then will our max connection limit be 137,068?

Comment: Why would you ever want to hit the limit anyway? You are likely to run out of other resources first.

Comment: The limit is per instance